# Destination Host Unreachable to host on LAN after some time

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, dd-wrt

I have internal network with the following setup:

- router - 192.168.1.1 - that is running dd-wrt
- rasberrypi - 192.168.1.190 (rp1.local) - that is running Rasberry Pi OS
- notebook - 192.168.1.185 - that is running Ubuntu
- some phones

Everything is working as expected - I am able to connect to rp1.local or 192.168.1.190 - but there is some strange behavior, that I am not able to figure out:

1. everything was working
2. 2023-12-27 22:00 - it's not possible to connect to rp1.local from the notebook, because the host name cannot be resolved, it's still possible to connect to the IP address 192.168.1.190
3. 2023-12-28 01:00 - it's still possible to connect to 192.168.1.190
4. 2023-12-28 11:00 - notebook is not able to connect (ping/http) to the rasberry pi IP address 192.168.1.190 (ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE / Destination Host Unreachable), some phones are still able to connect to that IP address
5. 2023-12-28 15:00 - none of the phones is able to connect to that IP address

During all that I can still connect to the router - 192.168.1.1 and from that router I can access 192.168.1.190 (or just rp1).

This has happened to me several times, but in the past it has resolved in few hours.

### Other information:

#### On the notebook:

```bash
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:d0:2b:0a:04:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:71:d9:9c:82:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.185/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 3925466sec preferred_lft 3925466sec
    inet6 fe80::352b:2ef9:850:124e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

-----

resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp3s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp2s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

-----

grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

#### Rasberry PI

```bash
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:34:c7:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:34:c7:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.190/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 3927658sec preferred_lft 3927658sec
    inet6 fe80::a22e:9352:19e5:9fab/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

-----

resolvectl
Failed to get global data: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.resolve1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

# but it wasn't there, so I had installed sudo apt-get install systemd-resolved

-----

grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

#### On the router

```bash
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc sfq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:4f:57:8f:19:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: vlan1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP 
    link/ether 70:4f:57:8f:19:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vlan2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 70:4f:57:8f:19:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.236.203/24 brd 10.2.236.255 scope global vlan2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 70:4f:57:8f:19:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:4f:57:8f:19:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP 
    link/ether 70:4f:57:8f:19:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

On the router I was also manually adding some rules to open some ports, but from the IP tables output it's hard to say, which ones it could be. Furthermore, they would most likely not cause this type of behaviour.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please run `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` and `resolvectl` on the RasPi and the Ubuntu notebook, and add the outputs into your original question.

Comment: Also, please make a note of when you have last rebooted the RasPi. When you get to your stage 5, check the uptime of the RasPi to see if it has crashed and rebooted on its own.

Comment: Assuming the rpi is over wifi & not ethernet, the typical reason for not contacting the rpi over wifi is power saving. Turn it off with `iw dev wlan0 set power_save off`. I would also ensure you that was done with any wifi connection.

Comment: @Bib: Thanks for help. But how it explains, that I can access it from other devices? I am not able to access it from my notebook for few hours, but I am still able to access it from the router and phone?

Comment: @telcoM: I have updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) sometimes it's not possible to connect to rp1.local from the notebook, because the host name cannot be resolved

The notebook seems to be using the router as its DNS resolver, and in addition it has two ways to resolve hostnames in the local network segment: LLMNR (through `systemd-resolved` set to `+LLMNR`) and mDNS (through `mdns4_minimal` in `nsswitch.conf`).

You did not have `systemd-resolved` installed on the RasPi until now, then unless there is a `llmnrd` running on the RasPi, there would have been nothing on the RasPi that would have answered to LLMNR queries - so mDNS would have been the most likely way the RasPi's hostname is getting resolved. The responder component in the RasPi would most likely be `avahi-daemon`, as it's been part of the default installation of the RasPi OS and most other Linux distributions.

So, that would suggest a problem in mDNS resolution. Given that mDNS uses multicasts, there is a number of things that might be going wrong with it.

- Have you filtered UDP port 5353?
- Have you filtered the multicast address range (224.0.0.0...239.255.255.255)?
- Have you filtered the IGMP protocol, or are there network switches using IGMP snooping? If IGMP snooping is in effect, you should also have an IGMP querier, or else there will be no IGMP reports to snoop on, and the switch(es) will eventually conclude that nobody needs multicast traffic forwarded to it, and so will stop passing it.

> 2.) when 1 happens, then after few hours (even after notebook restarts), the notebook is not able to connect (ping/http) to the rasberry pi IP address 192.168.1.190 (ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE / Destination Host Unreachable)

This might be the result of WiFi power saving, as @Bib said in the comments. Bib's suggestion of `iw dev wlan0 set power_save off` would switch it off until next reboot, or if you're using NetworkManager on the RasPi, then `nmcli c mod <connection name> 802-11-wireless.powersave disable` would persistently disable it.

> 3.) when 2 is happening, some of the phones are still able to access it, but some don't.

This might be a result of different mDNS/ARP cache lifetimes on some of the phones. Basically, the RasPi might be temporarily unable to answer to mDNS or even ARP queries because of power saving, but will wake up and respond if someone already knows its MAC address and sends packets to it.

> 4.) when I use telnet to connect to the router - 192.168.1.1, I can access 192.168.1.190 from the router

Together with 2.) this indicates the RasPi is still alive on IPv4 and responds when queried directly. Have you perhaps done some firewall rules that might interfere with ARP resolution on the notebook? Or is it possible that you might have an IP address conflict on 192.168.1.190? If 192.168.1.190 is statically assigned to the RasPi, is it either outside the range of addresses the router will assign dynamically over DHCP, or has the address .190 reserved for the RasPi in the router's DHCP server configuration?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I didn't have any static leases. But I have realized, that I could create some. So I have created ones, and then I have bricked my router. I have forgotten, that this is the reason, why there were none.

Now I have vanilla dd-wrt. And on the rp1:

resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 3 (wlan0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

Comment: Okay, so now the rp1 is active on LLMNR too. Did it cause any change in the problem behavior?

Comment: Now it is working for 4 days. Thanks for help. :)